# Drag and Drop document in a library with multiple content types associated

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, drag-and-drop

In a library with multiple Content type assigned how can I choose the CT in the document if i'm using drag and drop? How can I change the CT in case there is a CT associated per default?

Comment: Click "Edit properties" on the list item, then on top of the form that opens you have a drop-down for selecting content type

Comment: What happens if I have a Custom form? How could I show that dropdown? What's the SharePoint internal name for that element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drag and Drop is for only uploading the files into the documents library with minimal effort. It cannot help you to add meta data to the documents while doing so. You should be editing each file to add meta data to the document separately. Default content type will be applied while drag and drop.

Let me know if you have any questions.